# How do I use Anchor on the client side?

Tags: anchor

The first step to communicating with the program using Anchor seems to be creating the connection and setting the provider:

```
const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(config.rpcUrl);
const provider = await getProvider(wallet, connection);
anchor.setProvider(provider);
```

The problem here is that `wallet` has to be of type `NodeWallet` which requires a `keypair`. Since the wallet on the client side does not expose the private key, I don't understand how I can use Anchor there (or if it's even possible). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should go something like this:

```
import { useConnection, useAnchorWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

const { connection } = useConnection();
const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
```

and then your provider would be:

```
import {AnchorProvider} from "@project-serum/anchor"

const provider = new AnchorProvider(
    connection,
    wallet as unknown as AnchorWallet,
    {}
);
```

and then your program:

```
import {Program} from "@project-serum/anchor"
import { IDL, MyGenericProgram } from "<path to mygenericprogram.ts>";

const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
const program = new Program<MyGenericProgram>(IDL, PROGRAM_ID, provider);
```

The actual boilerplate code to set up the connection can be found [in the dapp scaffold here](https://github.com/solana-labs/dapp-scaffold).